# Get total time of all resources loaded from Chrome's Network Tab?

Tags: google-chrome, timeline

Chrome's Network Tab is so close to telling me everything I need. The red mark on the image below is the very end of loading the page, resources and ajax requests, but it doesn't actually tell me what the figure is.

It looks like I have to guess that it's 1.50 seconds or so.

Is there anywhere here that tells me that figure in seconds?

[image: Chrome Network Tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. The bar at the very bottom indicates the total load time in text form:

[image: Arrow indicates total load time]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. Though, if you had access to those requests, you could query the timestamp `new Date().getTime()` as early in the page as possible, and then query the timestamp again after your request is received and get the difference of the two in milliseconds.